# Youtube on AppleTV, continuously?

Tags: appletv, youtube

Is there a way, with the current AppleTV, to watch a bunch of Youtube videos without having to select each one by hand?

That is, either by entering some keywords to search for, or by providing it with a 'playlist' somehow.

Order isn't important.  Exact matching isn't important.

A method for doing this that involved streaming from a Mac would be fine, too, though I don't have a Mac capable of Airplay Mirroring, so that specific feature won't help me.

Comment: used to work this way + the exact same way for Vimeo.
Not anymore however. 3th gen Apple TV + 'dumb TV'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked at an Apple store, and basically the answer is "no".

The best workaround we could come up with is creating a Youtube account, making a playlist on Youtube, adding all the videos I want to that, and then playing them through AppleTV.  It's not exactly convenient, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. 
Just add your videos to your "watch later" playlist. 
And just play. 
It will play all the videos uninterrupted. 
N-joy